# Is there a way to retrieve requested windows username from WCF method

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I am using Custom binding in my WCF services and Proxies. I am creating proxies by inheriting from DuplexClientbase. Is there a option in WCF which helps me to get the username, who invoked the method?

Here is my binding

```
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="CustomPipeBinding" maxConnections="10" openTimeout="01:20:00" receiveTimeout="20.00:00:00" sendTimeout="01:20:00" closeTimeout="01:20:00">
            <windowsStreamSecurity protectionLevel="None" />
            <namedPipeTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="CustomTcpBinding" maxConnections="10" openTimeout="01:20:00" receiveTimeout="20.00:00:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" closeTimeout="01:20:00">
            <windowsStreamSecurity protectionLevel="None" />
            <reliableSession />
            <tcpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your service to require impersonation as [outlined in this MSDN article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Since you are defining a custom binding, you'll need to add the required security element config to allow WCF to pass the Windows credentials from the client to the service.

In your service code, you'll need to access the `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity` static property to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks :) I am using ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name to get the username. And in the binding, I removed the protectionLevel="None", by default it is EncryptAndSign. :)